# What's the relation between WS and socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I just installed socket.io for the first time, and at the end it gave me this message:

```
To install WS with blazing fast native extensions, use
<npm install ws --ws:native>
```

What does that mean? Is WS replacement for socket.io? I googled around and I can't figure it out. Or is it replacement for node.js? Or is it something I can install alongside socket.io and node.js?

Also I assume the message refers to this [ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws)?

Comment: The WS(https://github.com/einaros/ws) and socket.io(https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io) are two different frameworks/libs for achieving websocket impl. it shall be a replacement for socket.io and depends on the requirement you have. As mentioned by Andrey, socket.io supports few more transport methods. WS lib is not a replacement for node JS and yes it can work along with the node JS. But you dont have to include socket.io and ws in the same app, if you're focusing only in web socket based communications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, [ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws) is a dependency of `socket.io-client`, which is a dependency of `socket.io`. If you want to build native extensions for `ws`, you can pass `--ws:native` to `npm`.

You see the message because `ws` echo it when not being installed with `--ws:native`. You can safely ignore the message, or try passing `--ws:native` to `npm` when installing `socket.io`.

AFAICT, `socket.io-client` only uses it to connect to a `socket.io` server from node.js -- i.e. only for testing purposes. So it really shouldn't matter whether you compile it with native extensions or not.

Answer (score 16):

[Websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) (or ws) is one possible transport for socket.io (others are [flashsocket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-181c51321220efd9d1c-8000.html), [htmlfile](http://cometdaily.com/2007/11/18/ie-activexhtmlfile-transport-part-ii/), [xhr-polling and jsonp-polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29#Ajax_with_long_polling))

socket.io is basically a wrapper to help you transparently use best transport available in your browser

Comment: Good answer(probably accepted answer). A list or the transports can be found at http://socket.io/#browser-support

Comment: Thanks. But, what does the message mean? Why does socket.io give such message at the end of installation? Are they suggesting I should remove socket.io and install ws?

Comment: -1 as The 'ws' in the question does not refer to Websockets - it refers to the npm library named ws.